# how can I prove that $D^{-1}R$ has a unique maximal ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring without zero divisors & let $P$ be a prime ideal.

I have shown that $D=R\setminus P$ is a non-empty multiplicative closed set without zero-divisors.

Now how can I prove that $D^{-1}R$ has a unique maximal ideal?

Comment: It is not necessary to assume that $R$ has no zero divisors.

Comment: Perhaps the OP intended to eliminate localizations which wind up being the zero ring, in which case there aren't any maximal ideals. In that case it would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M = D^{-1}P = \bigg\{ \frac{x}{d} : x \in P$, $d \in D\bigg\}$. Observe that since $P$ is a prime ideal $P \neq R$ so it follows that $D^{-1}P \neq D^{-1}R$ and thus $D^{-1}P$ is a proper ideal of $D^{-1}R$. Now suppose $z \notin M$. Write $z = \frac{y}{d}$ where $y \in R$ and $d \in D$. Since $z \notin M$ it follows that $y \notin P$. Hence $y \in D$. Now we construct $w = \frac{d}{y} \in D^{-1}R$ since $d \in R$. Hence $zw = 1$ and thus $z$ is a unit. This shows that any element that is not in $M$ must be a unit and this this is a unique maximal ideal.

Answer (score 2):

First determine the candidate for being the maximal ideal. Then prove that everything outside that candidate is a unit (has an inverse).

The candidate seems to be $\tilde{P}:=\{p/q:\text{ with }p\in P\text{ and }q\in D\}$.

If $a/b\notin \tilde{P}$ then $a\notin P$. Hence $a/b$ has an inverse $b/a$.

Why there is no other maximal ideal $M$. Take $x\in M\setminus \tilde{P}$. Then $x$ isa unit and that forces $D^{-1}R=M$ and $M$ can't be maximal.

Comment: So what are the candidate for being the maximal ideal?